# Error CS2007: Unrecognized option: /analyzerconfig

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, command-prompt, roslyn

I have a Unity project which I use Roslyn for Code Analysis and I found that you can get the warnings and errors report from console using msbuild.

In the PC I have VS 2019 version 16.6.3, it gave the following error that I will comment below and updated to version 16.11.9, thinking it was the incompatibility and still gets the error. I tried running the command described below on other PCs with other versions of VS and it works fine, but I have not been able to identify what makes the command work well.

**Command**:
By running the following line in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019:
`msbuild ScriptsAssembly.csproj /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /t:Clean;Rebuild`
I expect to see the total number of warnings for the project and zero errors with successful execution like this:

[image]

Instead I get the following **error**:

```
CSC : error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '/analyzerconfig:C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\.editorconfig' [C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\SimpleJSON
.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\SimpleJSON.csproj"
(default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\ScriptsAssembly.csp
roj" (Clean;Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

...
"C:\Users\...\...\...\...\UnityProject\Project.csproj" (Clean;Rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\...\...\...\...\UnityProject\SimpleJSON.csproj" (default target) (2:3)
 ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  CSC : error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '/analyzerconfig:C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\.editorconfig' [C:\Users\...\Documents\...\...\UnityProject\SimpleJS
ON.csproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.91
```

What I expect to see is a thousand warnings, instead of 1.
I don't know if I am missing a package to install in VS. I have seen the error that the compiler message mentions in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs2007), but it doesn't help me much.
Any idea, or help is welcome.

Comment: What’s your Roslyn version? You can see which Roslyn package versions are supported for different versions of Visual Studio from this page(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/roslyn-version-support?view=vs-2022 ). Update to the correct version may solve your problem. Here is a similar case, hope it helps you.( https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1630-preview-2-new-build-error-csc-error-cs2007-un/702183?viewtype=all ).

Comment: @Jingmiao Xu-MSFT Good point, I am going to check it out, thank you.

Comment: Hi, any update about the issue?

Comment: Hello, the issue was not due to incompatibility, rather it was due to the commnad line, I was using the Roslyn one instead of using the MSBuild one, with this I was able to run without errors.